# How to set up a cron job for PHP on IIS?

Tags: iis, cron

How would I go about setting up a PHP cron job in IIS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cron jobs are usually not executed via http servers, so use the Task Scheduler to execute the php interpreter and provide the physical path to your php script as a commandline argument.

Comment: Thanks for your response, How would I use the Task Scheduler? Sorry I'm not at all versed with IIS.

Comment: That's great, thanks! One question though, the only options are for daily, weekly, monthly, one time only, when computer starts, and when I log on. How would I go about setting it to run every minute?

Comment: I know you may have found it after 3 years, but for new readers: To set a different time schedule (more than once a day), select "Create Task" instead of "Create Basic Task".